# Horizontal scrolling page weird behaviour on mobile chrome

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with my website that I wanted to do a little bit differently. Basically I have 4 sections with 100vh and 100vw and you scroll them horizontally with menu buttons. Now I'm having some trouble with mobile Chrome version. In Firefox (desktop and mobile) everything works as it should.

Here is the site in question (production code): http://dobrywebdev.pl/new

And here is the source code: https://github.com/michalgrochowski/dobrywebdev-v2

What are my problems:

- First and most annoying - you can scroll the page vertically outside html and body region - why? Dev tools show that both have the exact same height and below them there are nothing, but you can still scroll it down. On firefox - works like a charm.
- Second - why the nav is exactly 100vw on desktop version (Chrome and firefox) and is fixed just fine (see logo for example), but on mobile it turns to exactly 400vw (body width) if it's set to width: 100vw and max-width: 100vw? Again - Firefox just fine. What's funnier - Chrome devtools shows that the nav is in fact 100vw, but why it is not? Because of that both logo and hamburger does not respect the position: fixed and acts as absolute, which is not what I want.
- And finally why can you scroll the page if html have overflow: hidden and body have overflow-x: hidden and only overflow-y: scroll? And, as you've propably guesed by now - on Firefox it is fine.

Honestly I don't see anthing that could cause that and I would very much appreciate any help, because it is driving me nuts. I don't even want to think what it look like in Safari...

Oh, and the funniest part - IE11 and Edge are just fine too!

EDIT:
NAV component .scss:

```
.nav__logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 1.5rem;
    left: 2rem;
    width: 15rem;
}

.nav {
    @include flex-center-row;
    width: 100vw;
    max-width: 100vw;
    height: 6rem;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1rem;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.nav__list {
    @include flex-center-row;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0;
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        display: none;
    }
}

.nav__list--mobile {
    @include flex-center-column;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 3.5rem;
    width: 100vw;
    display: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 3;
}

.nav__item {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    display: block;
}

.nav__item--mobile {
    width: 100vw;
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 4;
    padding: 1rem 0 1rem 0;
}

.nav__link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}

.nav__link--mobile {
    z-index: 5;
}

.nav__link:hover, .nav__link:focus {
    color: #666;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.nav__hamburger {
    color: #333333;
    font-size: 3rem;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    @include mq-min(851px) {
        display: none;
    }
}
.nav__close-menu {
    @extend .nav__hamburger;
    display: none;
}
```

And used mixins:

```
@mixin flex-center-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

@mixin flex-center-column {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Relevant body and sections scss:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.6;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    color: #333;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 400vw;
    @include flex-center-column;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
}

// Main layout

.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 400vw;
    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

// Main Section

.main-section {
    width: 100vw;
    max-height: 100vh;
    @include flex-center-column;
    overflow: hidden;
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        max-width: 100vw;
    }
}

.main-section__title {
    font-size: 7rem;
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        font-size: 4rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.main-section__subtitle {
    font-size: 4rem;
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}

// Sections styles

.section-wrapper {
    @include flex-center-row;
    width: 100vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
}

.section {
    @include flex-center-column;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    @include mq-minmax(320px, 968px) {
        width: 95%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    @include mq-minmax(969px, 1200px) {
        width: 90%;
    }
    @include mq-min(1201px) {
        width: 117rem;
    }
}

.section--about {
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5rem;
        left: 100vw;
    }
}

.section--projects {
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5rem;
        left: 200vw;
    }
}

.section--contact {
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        width: 100vw;
        position: absolute;
        top: 5rem;
        left: 300vw;
    }
}

.section__title {
    font-size: 4rem;
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        width: 95%;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

.section__subtitle {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        width: 95%;
        font-size: 1.8rem;
        text-align: center;;
    }
}

.section__description {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    @include mq-max(850px) {
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
}
```

And finally, the markup:

```
<body id="body" class="body"> 
        <nav class="nav">
            <a class="nav__link" href="#start" title="">
                <img class="nav__logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <ul class="nav__list">
                <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link nav__link--about" href="#start" title="">...</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link nav__link--about" href="#about" title="">...</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link nav__link--projects" href="#projects" title="">...y</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item"><a class="nav__link nav__link--contact" href="#contact" title="">...</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav__list--mobile">
                <li class="nav__item nav__item--mobile"><a class="nav__link nav__link--mobile" href="#start" title="">...</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item nav__item--mobile"><a class="nav__link nav__link--mobile" href="#about" title="">...</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item nav__item--mobile"><a class="nav__link nav__link--mobile" href="#projects" title="">...</a></li>
                <li class="nav__item nav__item--mobile"><a class="nav__link nav__link--mobile" href="#contact" title="">...</a></li>
            </ul>
            <button class="nav__hamburger icon-menu"></button>
            <button class="nav__close-menu icon-cancel"></button>
        </nav> 
    <main class="container">
        <div class="section-wrapper" id="start">
            <section class="main-section fade-in">
                <h1 class="main-section__title">...</h1>
                <h2 class="main-section__subtitle">...</h2>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="section-wrapper" id="about">
            <section class="section section--about fade-in">
                <h2 class="section__title">...</h2>
                <h3 class="section__subtitle">...</h3>
                <p class="section__description">...</p>
                <h3 class="section__subtitle">...</h3>
                <div class="skills">
                    Icons
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="section-wrapper" id="projects">
            <section class="section section--projects fade-in">
                <h2 class="section__title">Projekty</h2>
                <div class="projects owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                    <div class="projects__project">
                        Project
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        <div class="section-wrapper" id="contact">
            <section class="section section--contact fade-in">
                <h2 class="section__title">Kontakt</h2>
                <div class="contact">
                    <form class="form" action="formularz.php" method="POST">
                        Form
                    </form>
                    <div class="socials">
                        Some more icons
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>
    <footer id="footer" class="footer">
            <p class="footer__copyright"></p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Please put the source code into the question. Not an external link. Your issue is probably inherited margin/padding values for whatever block element you have set `100vw`, `100vh` on, as well as not correctly setting the correct `box-sizing` parameter.

Comment: There is quite a lot of code, that's why there is a link to GitHub and a Live site, so you can see the problem for yourself. As to your solution - there is no inherited padding or margin, and box-sizing is set properly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I would think the most annoying issue is because your sections are flex items and by default `align-items` is `stretch` so your sections takes on the tallest flex item

Comment: @grhu, that's why you should only post the *relevant* CSS code in the question!

Comment: Here, I've added relevant code. As you can see, there is a lot of it, because I have a few problems with different parts of the page. @Huangism - all sections are flex items, but align-items is not stretch.

Comment: @grhu align-items is set on the flex container and not on flex items, your overall `.container` has no align-items set so it defaults to stretch. Also that container is part of your issue on mobile. It has a width of 400vw so the entire page width in chrome is 400 vw. Wrap your main with a container and set it to width 100% and overflow hidden. That will solve your mobile nav issue on chrome.

Comment: @Huangism I don't quite understand what you want me to do - the page is supposed to be 400vw, but the overflow should be hidden so you could not swipe it - only menu buttons should allow you to change sections, and that's how it works on Firefox and Edge (IE too). Adding align-items: center to .container so it overwrites default stretch and width: 100% doesn't help either. Take a look at the page in Firefox dev tools to see what it should look and work like.

Comment: @grhu your page is 400vw wide and I guess when you have position fixed on chrome and set 100vw it takes on the full width of the page. In this case, your hamburger menu is on the right side and it is off screen. Anyway someone has finally removed the position fixed on the hamburger as it was not needed and the mobile issue is solved

Comment: @Huangism Well yes, the hamburger now is where it should be, but still scrolling the page (wchich should not be possible with overflow: hidden everywhere) leaves nav on first section, and not fixed to the viewport like it should.

Comment: 1 problem at a time, what scrolls? mobile or desktop? device sim or regular chrome in phone size?

Comment: Mobile, both, like I said please check the page both in Firefox and in Chrome in device sim to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after searching for few days, asking on few Facebook front-end groups, reddit and here I couldn't find any solution - I've decided to just use OwlCarousel2 and make each section a Owl item. It works like a charm.

I didn't wanted to do that, but it seems that there is a weird bug and nobody knows how to fix it.